# How to encrypt data in MS SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, encryption, entity-framework-5

Am writing web application using ASP.NET MVC 4, Entity Framework 5 and SQL Server 2008. I am uncomfortable with the idea of creating database in hosting provider environment in Unencrypted form.

Is there any easy way to achieve complete data encryption in Database? Either at database end or application code end without much changes in existing application logic.

Comment: No point, if people can reach the db, then encrypting it or not is useless..

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934049.aspx

Comment: However. What are you trying to encryption for? What are you trying to protect? Data in Transit? Data at rest?

Comment: @Aron: Data at rest. I feel DB Admin at Hosting Provider end can easily read data if he has evil intent!! Ain't it?

Comment: @Anji give up. TDE will not help. Nothing will help. Unless you store all your data encrypted and transmit it encrypted and only decrypt it when its off your Hosting Provider. That would not be transparently implemented.

Comment: @Aron Yes, you are right. I want to just raise barrier so that "SELECT *" won't yield data for Admin(read as except me), unless he/she knows how encryption works and where keys are stored in SQL server.

Comment: @Anji now that has the stupidest thing I've ever heard. You want encryption that is transparent (without much change in existing app logic) and is difficult to bypass by system admin. Think about the logic there for a second.